# Android: How to store thousands of strings in a efficient way?

Tags: android

I am new to android app development, am developing a dictionary like app which contains thousands of strings, I want to know where and how to store the strings in a efficient way as it consumes much memory?

Comment: You may consider saving to disk rather than memory. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Try a ormlite sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the SQLite system. The String is the PRIMARY KEY and the meaning is the second column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html), it's a java database